# What is the best way to add page transitions to Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to add page transitions to my Nextjs app. What should I do to add that?

Comment: Page transition is a large concept, you want to add effect when users are navigating thru you pages ?

Comment: Yes, I am hoping to add effect on loading as well navigating through the pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can install the dependency `react-transition-group`

   `$ npm install react-transition-group`
2. create a `transition_sample.js` or `transition_sample.tsx`component in the component folder
3. Next, import the `transition_sample.js` or `transition_sample.tsx` component to your `layouts/MainLayout` or `_app.js` or `_app.tsx` if you're doing this in the `_app.js/_app.tsx` be sure to replace children with `<Component {...pageProps} />`
4. Import `useRouter` from `next//router` and pass the pathname to location props
5. All done then use the `MainLayout` in your `pages` and to use the layout wrap your pages with `MainLayout`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! The explanation too has helped me

Answer (score 2):

You can use libraries like [Framer Motion](https://www.framer.com/motion/) or [Barba js](https://barba.js.org/).

Comment: Ok I'll check it out

Comment: Refer this 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMucZErEdZg ,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4FXRmkdt3_8